Translation choices for the words "pray" in Acts 7:59 and "appeal" in Acts 25:11
Biblehub shows the word "prayed" in Acts 7:59 used by the New International Version Bible is derived from the Greek ἐπικαλούμενον (epikaloumenon). This is the same word used in Acts 25:11 for the word "appeal".
Why did the New International Version used the word "pray" in Acts 7:59 when the Greek origin clearly means appeal as shown on Biblehub.
Acts 25:11's I "appeal"
I appeal
ἐπικαλοῦμαι (epikaloumai)
Verb - Present Indicative Middle - 1st Person Singular
Strong's 1941: (a) To call (name) by a supplementary (additional, alternative) name, (b) mid: To call upon, appeal to, address.
Acts 7:59 Stephen "appealed"
ἐπικαλούμενον (epikaloumenon)
Verb - Present Participle Middle - Accusative Masculine Singular
Strong's 1941: (a) To call (name) by a supplementary (additional, alternative) name, (b) mid: To call upon, appeal to, address.
How do these translators choices for the word "pray" compare to Jesus use of the word "pray" in Matthew 6:7 "when ye pray (proseuchomai)"?

Despite being on the site much longer than me, the OP I think is encountering a problem I can sympathise with. The question is trying to discover something about the translation philosophy of why do NIV read a word a certain way, and receiving answers about how to read the word. Alex needed to already know that to be able to ask the question that Alex did ask.

For this it bears repeating that no translator is under any obligation to render the original's words consistently in the receiving language. NIV have "pray" in Acts 7:59 and "appeal" in Acts 25:11 and in principle that is a non-issue and not of interest.
Some translations do attempt to, despite the famous advice of Cicero against going "verbum pro verbo." Oddly it hasn't been mentioned before on this site and is often mis-quoted so I'll share a link and the quote: https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0543%3Achapter%3D5)
De Optimo Genere Oratorum
I translated the most famous speeches of two most eloquent men from the Attic style, Aeschines and Demosthenes, which are contradictory to each other; and I did not translate them as an interpreter, but as an orator, preserving the same meanings and their forms as if they were figures, using words suited to our custom. In this, I did not find it necessary to translate word for word, but I preserved the whole force and style of the words.
It's quite neat and proves Cicero's point that "verbum pro verbo" doesn't mean "word for word" (because "word for word" has become an English idiom).
The hazard for NT translators is 1:1 substitution with each Greek word having to be always rendered with the same English word. To the uneducated this tactic looks strict and professional and consistent, but unless it's to process the author's jargon this really just opens the door to the translator (or reader) departing from the original to generate a new text in the destination language. A translator who does this is either a knave or a fool (and with bible translators it's often the former).

When NIV's translation choices are strange, it's often because they are going for readability, doctrinal conformity, or modern sensitivity issues. The example the OP wants to know about, fortunately for me, is the first and a little bit of the second.
'call out' is harder to read than 'pray' - - because
(1) 'call out' is an idiom. And it's confusible: meaning to exclaim or to publicly criticize or to publicly seek support.
(2) It's two words so there's one more word
For you or I as literate users of a scholarly website about a relatively difficult ancient religious text, it might seem strange for NIV to have placed any weight on such things. But they need to reach (and also "reach" in the evangelical sense) people with low reading-ages, actual children, people whose first language isn't English, people whose dialects haven't existed very long, people with communication difficulties (well you get the idea)
When NIV get to Acts 25:11, they can't do the same - because of the point everyone else has raised, that in this passage the term ἐπικαλοῦμαι refers to the technical legal appeal.
For NIV, we'd expect ἐπικαλοῦμαι in Strongs sense 5, and προσεύχομαι to probably get bundled together, along with εὔχομαι, αἰτέω, ἱκετεύω, תָּפַל, פָּלַל, קָרָא, זָֽעַק, תָּנָא and anything else.
This is the bible they give away in the churches on really cheap paper so if they can boil the holy scripture's nuanced vocabulary down to "pray" and let the pastors teach people what prayer is, they have reduced confusion and provided a more versatile tool to pastors.
I dislike that, because in the process the word "pray" stops meaning to beseech or to beg (and to be able to take 'Caesar' or the man on the Clapham omnibus as a predicate) and begins to become "that thing Christians do in their heads".
Using language places it under strain, and NIV is in such wide circulation that they should be mindful of that.

Let's look at the Greek in Acts 7:59

The translation of “pray” might not be the most accurate, but it still makes sense within the context.
Another use of the word is in Acts 25:11.

For if I am an offender, or have committed anything deserving of
death, I do not object to dying; but if there is nothing in these
things of which these men accuse me, no one can deliver me to them. I
appeal to Caesar.” (Acts 25:11)

Here Paul makes a formal legal appeal to Caesar, which is a legal proceeding. Here, “appeal” is the appropriate translation because it reflects the legal context of seeking recourse.

Acts 25:11 (ἐπικαλοῦμαι): Translated as “appeal” to reflect Paul’s legal recourse.

So, what is prayer?

a solemn request for help or expression of thanks addressed to God or an object of worship. an earnest hope or wish. [Oxford languages]



a devout petition to God or an object of worship.

a spiritual communion with God or an object of worship, as in
supplication, thanksgiving, adoration, or confession. [a]




Prayer is communication with God. [b]

In Acts 7:59 on the other hand, Stephen, while being stoned to death, is addressing Jesus, saying, "Lord Jesus, receive my spirit." Hardly something that could be said to be dealing with legal matters. Stephen calling out to Jesus in this moment can be seen as an appeal or request for Jesus to receive his spirit. This is not a legal action but a simple communication, a calling out to Jesus. An earnest hope or wish if you will.

Acts 7:59 (ἐπικαλούμενον): Translated as “prayed” in the NIV to reflect Stephen’s earnest communication with Jesus.

Overall, the specific choice of translation depends on the context. In this case, Stephen is talking to Jesus, whom he calls Lord. While “pray” might not perfectly reflect the Greek language, it does fit the given definition of what it means to pray.

The original meaning of the word in question does not support what you stated, "Calling out to God".

I see you edited your answer. So why do you think NIV chose the word pray to translate (epikaloumenon) to "call upon" or "appeal"?

The meaning of ἐπικαλέω (epikaleó) is given by BDAG as:

to call upon a deity for any purpose, to call upon, call out, eg, Rom 10:12, 13, 14, 2 Tim 2:22, Acts 2:22, 7:59, 9:14, 21, 22:16, 1 Cor 1:2, 1 Peter 1:17, etc
to address or characterize someone by a special term, call, give a surname, eg, Matt 10:3, 25, Acts 4:36, 10:5, 18, 32, 11:13, 12:12, 25, 13:1, 15:22, Luke 22:3, Heb 11:16, etc
a request to put to a higher judicial authority for review of a decision in a lower court, appeal, eg, Acts 25:11, 21, 25, 26:32, 28:19.
to invoke an oath, call on someone as a witness, eg, 2 Cor 1:23.

Thus, we have several shades of meaning all surrounding the central idea of calling out to someone.
In the case of meaning #1, in all cases, when the calling out is to a supernatural being, it is only to God and thus can be legitimately called, "praying".  Now, V59 should not be divorced from V60 -

(Acts 7:59, 60): While they were stoning him, Stephen called out,
“Lord Jesus, receive my spirit.” Falling on his knees, he cried out in
a loud voice, “Lord, do not hold this sin against them.” And when he
had said this, he fell asleep.

There are two things that are significant about this:

That Stephen prayed to “Lord Jesus” at all, implying Jesus was divine
That Stephen asked Jesus to receive his breath/spirit.  This is a direct allusion to at least two OT passages:


Ps 31:5 - Into Your hands I commit my spirit/breath; You have redeemed me, O LORD, God of truth.
Eccl 12:7 - before the dust returns to the ground from which it came and the spirit/breath returns to God who gave it.
In both cases, Stephen obviously believed that Jesus was the God who receives his breath/life as he died.  This is the reverse of what is recorded in Gen 2:7 where God bequeaths the breath of life to man (Adam).

Thus, Acts 7:59 is a perfect example of Stephen praying to Jesus.  See appendix below for more examples.  Thus, it appears to have been quite common for NT people to pray to Jesus.
APPENDIX - Prayers to Jesus
There are numerous cases in the NT of People praying directly to Jesus. Here is a sample:

John 4:10 - Jesus answered and said to her, "If you had known the gift of God and who it is saying to you, 'Give Me to drink,' you would have asked Him, and He would have given to you living water."
John 14:13, 14 -And I will do whatever you ask in My name, so that the Father may be glorified in the Son. If you ask Me for anything in My name, I will do it.
Acts 1:24, 25 - And they prayed, “Lord, You know everyone’s heart. Show us which of these two You have chosen to take up this ministry and apostleship, which Judas abandoned to go to his rightful place.”
Acts 7:59, 60 - While they were stoning him, Stephen appealed, “Lord Jesus, receive my spirit.” Falling on his knees, he cried out in a loud voice, “Lord, do not hold this sin against them.”
Acts 9:5 - “Who are You, Lord?” Saul asked. “I am Jesus, whom you are persecuting,” He replied.
1 Cor 1:2 - To the church of God in Corinth, to those sanctified in Christ Jesus and called to be holy, together with all those everywhere who call on the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, their Lord and ours
2 Cor 12:8, 9 - Three times I pleaded with the Lord to take it away from me. But He said to me, “My grace is sufficient for you, for My power is perfected in weakness.”
1 Tim 1:12 - I thank Christ Jesus our Lord, who has strengthened me, that He considered me faithful and appointed me to service.
Rev 5 contains numerous prayers of praise to Jesus, eg, V8-10, V11, 12, V13.
Rev 22:20 - He who testifies to these things says, “Yes, I am coming soon.” Amen. Come, Lord Jesus!
Matt 28:17 - When they saw Him, they worshiped Him [this one for completeness] See also Matt 2:11, 14:33, 28:9, Luke 4:8; 24:52; John 9:38, Rom 10:9, Heb 1:5, 6, Phil 2:10, etc.


Are all these calling out/praying have the same sense as praying to God? Can you also clarify for completeness how the same act of worship was rendered to both God and king David? 1 Chronicles 29:20

@AlexBalilo - first, 1 Chron 29:20 is in a different language and involves a verb בָּֽרְכוּ = to bless or kneel.  Prayer is not mentioned.  If you wish to ask about this text, ask another question.

Are all these calling out /praying have the same sense as praying to God? Worship is mentioned in your answer, that was why I asked you to clarify how the same act of worship can be rendered to both the king and God. The calling out that appear on your answer doesn't not appear to be the same as the word "pray" that Jesus used in  Matthew 6:7.

@AlexBalilo - of course they are different words, that is why one is calling out and the other praying - but prayer is, among other things, calling out to God.  "Lord save me" is as much a prayer as any other.

So the examples you cited  for the word (pray)ing to Jesus carry no religious supplication.

@AlexBalilo - any prayer to Jesus is significant.

Even more significant is that Jesus is not the hearer of prayer. It's his Father, YHWH. Psalm 65:2  Jesus himself prayed to his Father for strengthening. That is why the examples you cited for the word"pray"ing to Jesus carry no  religious supplication. That is why Jesus instructed his followers to pray to the Father instead of praying to him.

@AlexBalilo - well, you have decided what the Bible should say.  I read the Bible as it is.
